# Make a control break out of panel bounds

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, clipping

I was making some custom controls for WinForms and got myself into a problem. When resizing one of my controls, in a way that it would get longer than the panel bounds (height/width), it would just cut off. This behavior is expected but I wanted it to be different for this control. Is there anyway to make this work without bothering the person that would use these controls with control hierarchy? [Example of what i'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70Dne.png)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This behavior is normal. The panel clip the display to its bounds. To display the entire inner control you must set it outer i.e. change its parent. And if you want a control being over another control you must change the z-order.

Comment: @OlivierRogier This change must be made by the user who would be using the custom control -- that's not my intent. I was talking about something like the [ComboBox](https://i.imgur.com/WFZuF4K.png), when even though it's inside the panel, it's dropdown breaks out of the bounds of the panel; that's what i'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't understand. If I put a combobox with some items at bottom of a panel, the list does not clip at the border of the panel... Could you improve your question with more details, code and real image of your forms/controls, please?

Comment: That's what I want to do, make the custom control not clip, like the ComboBox doesn't.
Edit: [Video of my custom control X ComboBox](https://streamable.com/6220m)

Comment: What is the parent class of your custom control container? Where is the combobox: inside it or inside a control inside the custom control?

Comment: "What is the parent class of your custom control container?"
Right now I'm using panel since I find it way easier draw on it/handle events. Should I switch to ComboBox?

"Where is the combobox: inside it or inside a control inside the custom control?"
My custom control isn't a UserControl, it handles everything by itself. [My repo](https://github.com/ponei/SkeetUI/blob/dev/SkeetUI/skeetComboBox.cs)

Comment: I don't understand. You say you use a Panel, that is fine, but next you say that you don't use a usercontrol... So what do you use: you inherit of what to create your custom control? Can you add the code of the custom control, please?

Comment: I inherit "Panel". The Panel is the ComboBox -- It isn't a UserControl where it has a ComboBox. My code is in my repo (link above).

Comment: All seems to be fine and it works on my VS2017 .NET Framework 4.6.1. The code of your repo works.fine: http://www.ordisoftware.com/files/stack-overflow/skeetComboBox.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From one of OP's comments:

> ...I was talking about something like the ComboBox, when even though it's inside the panel, it's dropdown breaks out of the bounds of the panel...

The dropdown of a ComboBox (a ListBox) is shown as a top-level window (above all others); as such it is not parented to another control. You could do something similar using the MouseEnter/MouseLeave events to toggle the control to be top-level/normal.  It would only fully appear when the mouse enters it and it is changed to a top-level window.

The following is a minimal implementation of such a control.

```
class AutoTopLevelPanel : Panel
{
    private Control parentInternal;
    private int parentIndex = -1;
    private Point locationInternal;

    public AutoTopLevelPanel()
    {
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);

        if (parentIndex == -1)
        {
            parentIndex = Parent.Controls.IndexOf(this);
        }
        if (base.TopLevelControl != this)
        {
            parentInternal = Parent;
            locationInternal = Location;
            Location = Parent.PointToScreen(Location);
            Parent = null;
            SetTopLevel(true);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        if (base.TopLevelControl == this)
        {
            SetTopLevel(false);
            Parent = parentInternal;
            Parent.Controls.SetChildIndex(this, parentIndex);
            Location = locationInternal;
        }
    }

}
```